# Docker migration and permission issues

Tags: linux, docker, postgresql

I started a migration from the content of my docker host on maschine A (Debian Stretch) to maschine B (Debian Buster). I used rsync to copy my volumes /var/lib/openproject{pgdata, static}. Now it looks like, that the permissions on maschine B are wrong.

docker logs shows me following content:

```
Starting PostgreSQL 9.6 database server: mainError: Config owner (postgres:102) and data owner (app:1000)
do not match, and config owner is not root ... failed!
```

What are the correct permissions in this case? 
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: can you just check permission in place on A and add the same permissions on B ?

Comment: no I can't check it right now - it's offline right now. That's the reason why I'm asking.
I tried root:root and also 1000:1000.

Comment: The answer is right there in the log message - the postgres data directory and the config file aren't owned by the same user. You need to set the config file to be owned by either root or the same user that owns the data directory.

Answer (score 0):

I check on my docker postgresql and looks like this

```
ls -l /var/lib/postgresql/
drwx------   19 postgres root          4096 Aug 23 03:07 data
```

and inside the data directory

```
-rw-------    1 postgres postgres         3 May 17 02:05 PG_VERSION
drwx------    9 postgres postgres      4096 Jul  9 03:26 base
drwx------    2 postgres postgres      4096 Aug 23 03:08 global
drwx------    2 postgres postgres      4096 May 17 02:05 pg_commit_ts
drwx------    2 postgres postgres      4096 May 17 02:05 pg_dynshmem
-rw-------    1 postgres postgres      4535 May 17 02:05 pg_hba.conf
-rw-------    1 postgres postgres      1636 May 17 02:05 pg_ident.conf
drwx------    4 postgres postgres      4096 Aug 24 08:28 pg_logical
drwx------    4 postgres postgres      4096 May 17 02:05 pg_multixact
drwx------    2 postgres postgres      4096 Aug 23 03:07 pg_notify
drwx------    2 postgres postgres      4096 May 17 02:05 pg_replslot
drwx------    2 postgres postgres      4096 May 17 02:05 pg_serial
drwx------    2 postgres postgres      4096 May 17 02:05 pg_snapshots
drwx------    2 postgres postgres      4096 Aug 23 03:07 pg_stat
drwx------    2 postgres postgres      4096 Aug 24 08:30 pg_stat_tmp
drwx------    2 postgres postgres      4096 Aug 23 04:47 pg_subtrans
drwx------    2 postgres postgres      4096 May 17 02:05 pg_tblspc
drwx------    2 postgres postgres      4096 May 17 02:05 pg_twophase
drwx------    3 postgres postgres      4096 Aug 24 08:03 pg_wal
drwx------    2 postgres postgres      4096 Aug  6 19:21 pg_xact
-rw-------    1 postgres postgres        88 May 17 02:05 postgresql.auto.conf
-rw-------    1 postgres postgres     23841 May 17 02:05 postgresql.conf
-rw-------    1 postgres postgres        24 Aug 23 03:07 postmaster.opts
-rw-------    1 postgres postgres        94 Aug 23 03:07 postmaster.pid
```

So basically you ha to change ownership to

```
chow postgres:root /var/lib/postgresql/
chow -R postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

And permissions to

```
find /var/lib/postgresql/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
find /var/lib/postgresql/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
```